# How to remove onblur even listener using console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, window, onblur

A website shows poupup when I change tab but I don't want to see it again and again and again.
The code that is triggering popup looks similar to following:

```
window.onblur = function () {
              console.log("DO not change the tab else we will irritate you using popups")
}
```

How can I disable this `onblur` listener by using some command in browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried squashing this event? The code below is probably the code you are trying to edit. Can you try the other?

```js
  window.onblur = function () {
         document.body.style.backgroundColor='red';
        }
```

```js
   window.onblur = function () {
         document.body.style.backgroundColor='red';
        }

        window.onblur = function () {
         return false
        }
```